# GRAILS Multiple composite foreign keys sharing the same table field?

Tags: grails, foreign-keys, grails-orm, composite-key

I'm trying to use grails with an existing old style legacy db. I have composite keys everywhere (PK and FK) and... more FK sharing the same table column. An example:

All tables shares the "company" value.

```
class SalesOrder implements Serializable{

...
static hasMany = [items: SalesOrderItem]

static mapping = {
    table 'MYORDERTABLE'
    id composite: ["company", "orderId"], generator: "assigned"
```

Than my sales order items:

```
class SalesOrderItem implements Serializable{
     ....
     Material mat

     static belongsTo = [order: SalesOrder]

     static mapping = {

    table 'MYORDERITEMSTABLE'
    id composite: ["order", "lineNumber"], generator: "assigned"
    lineNumber column: 'ITEMNUMBER'

        columns { 
           order { column name:'COMPANY'
           column name:'ORDERNUMEBR' }
        }
```

All the previous code works (only with grails 2.0 M1). My "order" has a composite PK (company+orderId), my "orderLine" has a composite PK (company+orderId+orderLineId).

The problems come when I have other attributes with composite keys that shares the "company" attribute as one element of the FK, like

```
columns{    
    mat {   column name: 'COMPANY', insertable:false, updateable:false
    column name: 'MATTYPE'
            column name: 'MATCODE'
            column name: 'MATCODEEXT1'
            column name: 'MATCODEEXT2'
         } 
 }
```

This does not work, the error that comes out is

```
Repeated column in mapping for entity: SalesOrderItem 
column: COMPANY (should be mapped with insert="false" update="false")
```

And I'm stuck right here. If it was just one case, I would use some cheap & dirty workaround but I have plenty of cases like this.

Do you have any suggestion? Hint? Solution? Any help is appreciated?

Thanks,
Lorenzo

---

**Update**

I have found the following post with basically the same question about hibernate:

[should-hibernate-be-able-to-handle-overlapping-foreign-keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4231452/should-hibernate-be-able-to-handle-overlapping-foreign-keys)

and it seems that it is still an unresolved issue:

[hibernate jira](https://hibernate.onjira.com/browse/HHH-6221)

no hibernate, no gorm I suppose. As for a workaround I'm thinking on using the events aferLoad, beforeInsert, beforeUpdate to load/update the domain classes linked with this FK's.

Comment: I have post a similar solution here [Renaming composite foreign keys in GORM]
  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2204738/renaming-composite-foreign-keys-in-gorm/7518425#7518425